# What's the best way to find the version number of the latest starred version

Tags: commcare

My application has so many builds that I cannot find the starred build on the deploy page. What is the best way to get the version number of the latest starred build?

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `?limit=100` to the end of the releases page URL to load more releases at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the app on your phone and Update to Latest starred build to see what version number it is.  You wouldn't have to go through with the install either, it'll tell you the version before it asks you if you want to update.

You could also submit a form using WebApps and the form data will have the App Version # in it as part of the meta data.